# Pass method to Stream.forEach()

Tags: java, stream

I'm writing from text file to `ArrayList`. This is my code:

```
List<String> text = new ArrayList<String>();
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(path))) {
    stream.forEach(text::add); //the part I'm stucked with
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Actually, I've made `forEach(text::add)` kind of intuitionally and it works. Can you explain me internals of this part, what topics should I read about and what are alternatives? Oracle tells:

> forEach(Consumer< ? super T> action)
>   
> Performs an action for each
>   element of this stream.

So it's unclear for me how my code works.

Comment: The question is unclear as to what doesn't work. Off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part `text::add` is called a `MethodReference`.

See the official documentation from oracle for details and how it works: [MethodReference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)

This another nice article about `MethodReference`s, including examples with `forEach` [Using method references in Java 8](https://marcin-chwedczuk.github.io/method-references-in-java-8)

Comment: Thanks, it's helpful.

Comment: I've added another link, with `forEach` examples included